# How to organize an array that is returned using Curl?

Tags: python, linux, bash, curl, sh

I am using the following command to list all the images in a catalog:

```
curl -s http://internal.private.registry.com/v2/_catalog | python -c 'import sys,json;data=json.loads(sys.stdin.read()); print data["repositories"]'
```

It is giving the following output:

```
[u'centos', u'containersol/consul-server', u'containersol/mesos-agent', u'containersol/mesos-master']
```

How to organize the output in the following form:

```
Repo1: "centos"
Repo2: "containersol/consul-server"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider taking a look at [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) it's really quite fun to play with:

```
curl -s ... | jq -r '.repositories[0:2] | to_entries | map("Repo \(.key+1 | tostring): \"\(.value)\"")[]'
Repo1: "centos"
Repo2: "containersol/consul-server"
```

Breakdown:

```
.                 # Read stdin
repositories[0:2] # Take the first two from repositories array
| to_entries      # Convert to an array of object with key, value pairs:
                  # [ {"key": 0, "value": "..."}, {key: 1, "value": "..."} ]
| map("Repo"      # Map array
     + (.key+1 | tostring)
     + ": \""     # Literal : and "
     + .value
     + "\"")      # Literal "
[]                # Convert array to a newline separated list
```

`-r` prints output that are not JSON encoded, eg: `"abc"` -> `abc`

Comment: It seems jq is not installed on my company laptop and i dont have permission to install it  `-bash: jq: command not found`

Comment: @meallhour You can download a standalone binary if you want. I will however say Python is a fine alternative. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/